# How eligible is a BSc in applied math from a German FH (university of applied sciences) for a physics masters outside Germany?

Tags: mathematics, masters, physics, bachelor

I'd like to start with myself. I'm planning to transfer my studies to a German university. My objective is to become an astrophysicist. I want to have my Bachelor's in mathematics, Master's in physics *(astrophysics or particle)* and PhD in astrophysics.

I found a university of applied sciences *(Fachhochschule)* in Mittweida, Saxony. It offers a free, English course in applied mathematics, [and the curriculum looks similar to that of any math course](https://www.cb.hs-mittweida.de/fileadmin/_processed_/0/c/csm_Moduluebersicht_Tabelle_MA-B_2018_c3805b30fb.jpg) *(although there are some differences depending on the universities, this is why I added the curriculum for you to review as well, I think you would know it better).*

I am aware of the general differences between an FH and a Universtät in Germany, and that the recognition of a German FH degree depends on the university one is going to apply for a Master's degree. *(e.g.: [UCLA doesn't consider a FH degree as eligible,](https://grad.ucla.edu/admissions/required-academic-records/#:%7E:text=Holders%20of%20the%20Vordiplom%2C%20Zwischenpr%C3%BCfung%2C%20Bachelor/Bakkalaureus%2C%20or%20a%20diploma%20from%20a%20fachhochschule%20are%20not%20considered%20for%20graduate%20admission.) whereas [the University of Edinburgh does](https://www.ed.ac.uk/studying/international/european-union-postgraduate-entry-requirements/g-l/germany#:%7E:text=To%20be%20considered%20for%20admission%20to%20any%20of%20our%20taught%20masters%20programmes%2C%20you%20must%20normally%20hold%20a%20bachelor%20degree/Diplom/Magister%20Artium/Diplom%20(FH)%20in%20an%20appropriate%20subject%20from%20an%20accredited%20university%20or%20university%20of%20applied%20science.%C2%A0))*

What I wanted to know is, would an Applied Mathematics diploma create any obstacles in my way to obtaining a Master's degree in Physics?

Also, as mentioned in the 3rd paragraph, I am aware of the general difference; but to get more specific, how much would Applied Maths education at a FH differ from the same subject at a Universtät?

Comment: Applied math seems a long way from astrophysics. Why not a more direct route?

Comment: And why take a risk that a Fachhochschule diploma won't be accepted. A university seems a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear-cut answer to this question. It will **depend** very much **on the master programme (and its curriculum)** and the opinion of the programme director.

The best way is to just **write to them** and ask (with your documents attached). Note, that in many universities there is also a middle way between accepting and rejecting a candidate by asking the candidate to do some additional course work (e.g. in your case some physics basics).